# Return the result of select into a variable MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I try to set the result of a select in a variable(To show it in my result) but I obtain an error

This is my code :

```
SELECT 8_Type,SET @var= (select Name from variables where  Ch8_ID  = variables.ID)
FROM TTable ;
```

and when I change my code like bellow, this is what I want but I need to change the name of the column :

```
SELECT 8_Type, (select Name from variables where  Ch8_ID  = variables.ID)
FROM TTable ;![enter image description here][1]
```

I obtain in the column the query like this image.

[image: The second query]

Comment: Why are you using a subselect in SELECT clause?  I am not following what you are trying to do.

Comment: The error is private or do you want to share the error?

Comment: The error is : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a column alias for the expression...   `SELECT expr AS my_name` e.g.

```
SELECT 8_Type
     , (select Name from variables where Ch8_ID = variables.ID) AS my_name
 FROM TTable
```

MySQL will return "my_name" as the label for the column (in the metadata) for the resultset.

(But it's not at all clear what your SQL statement is trying to do though.)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT field AS put_name_result FROM ttable